# How to understand Bson Timestamp?

Tags: mongodb, bson

For Mongo Bson type Timestamp, there is a constructor: `BsonTimestamp(final int seconds, final int increment)`, how to understand the `increment`? what is the design consideration?

Answer (score 2):

[Timestamp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) is an internal BSON type used by MongoDB to reflect the operation time (`ts`) for entries in the [replication oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/).

The BSON Timestamp type is designed for the specific use case of logging ordered batches of time-based operations:

- the first 32 bits (`time_t`) are an integer value representing seconds since the Unix epoch
- the second 32 bits are an integer value (`ordinal`) indicating ordering within a given second

The design requirement for Timestamps is based on preserving strict ordering for oplog entries rather than time precision (eg milliseconds or microseconds). The leading time component gives a course granularity of seconds; appending an incrementing [ordinal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) ensures strict ordering of unique Timestamp values within a given second. Using an ordered sequence instead of time precision avoids pushing down the potential conflict of two operations that might occur in the same millisecond (or microsecond).

For application use cases you should use the [BSON Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) type instead of a Timestamp. A BSON Date is the same size (in bits) as a Timestamp, but provides more granularity for time:

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). This results in a representable date range of about 290 million years into the past and future.

Comment: Your answer repeats the documentation without any explanation. Could you explain what is the "incrementing ordinal"?

Comment: @pooya13 I revised my answer with some hopefully clearer elaboration. l may also have contributed to similar info in the documentation (I vaguely remember the description just being "internal BSON type" at some point). If this update is useful I'll submit a PR so the docs may be eventually consistent with my explanation :)

Comment: Yes @Stennie much better! Thanks